# Where in the Standard does it say that a member alias-declaration can be used as if it was a static member?

Tags: c++, alias, language-lawyer, c++14

Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A { int i; using Int = int; };

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(A::Int) << '\n';
}
```

It compiles and executes normally in [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/953568c85cf422da) and GCC. I know this looks obvious, but I couldn't find anything in the Standard (C++14) supporting the reference to `A::Int` in `main()`.

Comment: This is already C++11 valid code. Maybe check under aliasing? anyway it's not a member (as far as I know), it is just a typedef into A namespace

Comment: `A::Int` is a qualified-id that is looked up as described by §3.4.3.1.

Comment: I don't understand the question. It's no different than `sizeof(A::i)` no?

Comment: @Columbo I fail to see this in 3.4.3.1

Comment: @Barry My example was not very good. But you can try this: `main() { A::Int k = 0; std::cout << k << '\n'; }`. It will compile and execute normally.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil Of course. Why would it not?

Comment: @HansPassant Generic programming uses this all the time and apparently without a support from the spec.

Comment: @HansPassant What're you talking about? Presumably Bjarne has written pre-C++11 code with the standard containers that required him to write `C::iterator`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just your normal qualified lookup. From [basic.lookup.qual]:

> The name of a class or namespace member or enumerator can be referred to after the `::` scope resolution
>   operator (5.1) applied to a *nested-name-specifier* that denotes its class, namespace, or enumeration.

Then from [class.qual]:

> If the *nested-name-specifier* of a *qualified-id* nominates a class, the name specified after the *nested-namespecifier*
>   is looked up in the scope of the class (10.2), except for the cases listed below. The name shall
>   represent one or more members of that class or of one of its base classes (Clause 10). *[ Note:* A class member
>   can be referred to using a *qualified-id* at any point in its potential scope (3.3.7). *—end note ]* The exceptions
>   to the name lookup rule above are the following:
>
> - a destructor name [...]
> - a *conversion-type-id* of a *conversion-function-id* [...]
> - the names in a *template-argument* of a *template-id* [...]
> - the lookup for a name specified in a *using-declaration* [...]

The *nested-name-specifier* in your example is `A`, which is a class. None of those exceptions apply. So we just look up the name, `Int`, in the scope of class.

From [dcl.typedef]:

> A name declared with the `typedef` specifier becomes a *typedef-name*. Within the scope of its declaration, a
>   *typedef-name* is syntactically equivalent to a keyword and names the type associated with the identifier in
>   the way described in Clause 8. A *typedef-name* is thus a synonym for another type.
>   [...]
>   A *typedef-name* can also be introduced by an *alias-declaration*. The identifier following the using keyword
>   becomes a *typedef-name* and the optional *attribute-specifier-seq* following the identifier appertains to that
>   *typedef-name*. It has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the `typedef` specifier.

So your *alias-declaration* introduces the name `Int` into the scope of `A`, which is found according to the qualified lookup rules I just enumerated.

Comment: 3.3.7 doesn't  seem to say anything about the potential scope of an alias-declaration member. See the Note in [class.qual].

Comment: @WakeupBrazil Huh? "The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of the declarative region following the
name’s point of declaration, but also [...]". So it's clearly in the scope of `A`.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: Are you doubting that the `using` declaration has the same effect as a `typedef`, or that the scope of the typedef is like any other class member? Either way it looks like Barry's answer is both correct and complete. (Or am I missing your point?)

Comment: @Nemo Barry is justifying his answer using a lookup rule [class.qual]. But one has to show that a typedef (or an alias-declaration) has a potential scope that extends outside the class definition, i.e., that it has namespace scope, as a static data member. The problem is that there is no place in the spec (not that I know of) where this is specified. That's why I think the Note in [class.qual] is important `A class member can be referred to using a qualified-id at any point in its potential scope (3.3.7).`

Comment: @WakeupBrazil Its potential scope **does not** extend outside the class definition. That's why you need to qualify it with the class name - otherwise you could just say `Int`! And it's not a static data member. It's just a name.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil The concepts of *declarative region* and *scope* are related to parts of the program where the name can be referred to via an *unqualified-id*.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: Barry's [class.qual] quote says `...the name specified after the nested-name-specifier is looked up in the scope of the class`, which settles your question. I believe you are misunderstanding the definition of "scope". It is a purely lexical (i.e. textual, compile-time) concept, not a dynamic (run-time) one. The whole point of the `::` syntax is to let you "reach into" one scope from another scope. See section 3.3 [basic.scope].

Comment: @dyp `The concepts of declarative region and scope are related to parts of the program where the name can be referred to via an unqualified-id.` A static data member of a class is known to have a namespace scope (file scope). Nevertheless, you can't refer to such a member without a qualified-id in this scope.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil No, a static data member of a class **does not** have namespace scope. It has class scope. That's why need to qualify it with the class name to refer to it.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil Is there anything in the Standard that says that static data members of classes have namespace scope? I searched the Standard but only found that members of classes have class scope, and *member names of namespaces* have namespace scope.

Comment: @dyp Thanks for helping me to get rid of this awful misconception. I had this idea so ingrained in my mind that I never bothered to investigate, until I received your comment yesterday.